# fastlane error Failed to open TCP connection to olympus.itunes.apple.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

Tags: ios, fastlane, continuous-delivery

## Problem

I'm getting a new Fastlane error after the command below the line:

```
bundle exec fastlane beta --verbose
```

### Error Message

```
Failed to open TCP connection to olympus.itunes.apple.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

fastlane finished with errors
```

**Current step**: pilot

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

I've solved the issue with updating my fastlane version with the command line below:

```
bundle update fastlane
```

if you used [homebrew](https://brew.sh) fo installation of fastlane, use this:

```
brew upgrade fastlane
```

That's all.

Comment: in my case i installed fastlane with brew, so in order to update fastlane i had to use ```brew upgrade fastlane``` and it solved this issue

Comment: @stanislau-buzunko, I'm glad that it solved your issue, I added homebrew installation details.

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced this issue and got solution

1- check your internet connectivity.

2- try with different network.

3- If the above solution does not work then looking for update fastlane.

In my case this is due to change my internet provider.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like an internet / connection issue ie. something preventing the communication between your host and app store connect. I'd say try again after a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by turning off my wifi and switching back on.
This is the error I am getting.

```
Faraday http exception getting app: Failed to open TCP connection to api.appcenter.ms:443 (execution expired)
```

This problem is very random. Sometimes it works without any issues. I hope there is a permanent solution to this!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is just another error. We can't say all errors have no meaning at all, I guess.